# How to make status bar textcolor dark on button click in Dark mode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13, ios-darkmode

When I click on `Default` button status bar style changes `.black` in Normal mode 
But when I enable `Dark Mode` , status bar automatically becomes white and won't change back

I put the separate code to change it again but it won't work

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
@objc func defaultbutton()
{
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *)
    {
        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark
        {
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black                               
            print("status bar style changing is failing everytime it's enterng here")
        }
        else
        {
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override `preferredStatusBarStyle` property in your `viewController` to change your status bar color to dark in dark mode.

```
override  open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    get {
        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            return UIStatusBarStyle.darkContent
        } else {
            return UIStatusBarStyle.default
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested,it works fine for me. try this solution and let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: should I put this code in `IBAction` of `default` button ?

Comment: In your viewcontroller, you will override the default implementation of the viewcontrollers property.

Comment: to add this function in view controller I have to add version check and even after that it's still not working..... @Manikandan

Comment: make sure you removed other changes in statusBar like self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = .default